# are data sets obtained from a Normal distribution normal?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have 10 vectors each having 100,000 points ( Muscle activity obtained by sampling at a rate of 10 Khz). I take integral of each data set to have 10 values. I want to know whether these 10 values are normally distributed. ?

Comment: Your headline and your text ask different questions. If you "know" that your original data is normally distributed then you can derive that several operations like summing up, multiplying by constants and so on preserve normality. When you say in the text of the question that you take the integral, what do you do? Sum up and divide by the number of summands? Then the result will be normal if the original data was normal. If you e.g. take powers then the results will not necessarily be normal anymore.

Comment: I just read that your resulting data set consists of 10 values only  ... this is a small data set. So what I would do is first analyse the original data and then check if the operations that you perform preserve normality.

Comment: i simply do an integral in matlab on each of my vector Y which consist of 100,000 sample points.                              trapz(Y), computes an approximation of the integral of Y via the trapezoidal method

Comment: Then what you do is just taking differences of the data and mutiplying the data by constants. This will preserve normality.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as posted in my comments. You can first check whether your original data is normally distributed. Then when you do the integral by the trapezoidal rule you will preserve normality as the operations that are performed do. 
E.g. If $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed then also $X+Y$ or $X-Y$ or $a X + bY$ for arbitrary real number $a,b$. In short: if a vector $X$ is normally distributed then also linear transformations $A X $ are normal for some matrix $A$. Of course mean and variance change according to the transformation.

Comment: i checked with a qq plot that X is normally distributed and Y is not. However i want to compare X with Y. for now i am using mann-whitney test. Does it makes sense or there is better way to compare these data ?                                           X=[1.59e-05 1.45e-05 1.65e-05 1.63e-05 1.670e-05 2.03e-05 1.3e-05 1.71e-05 1.88e-05 1.78e-05]
 Y=[1.12e-05 1.18e-05 1.16e-05 1.19e-05 1.13e-05 1.39e-05 1.22e-05 1.44e-05 1.35e-05]

Comment: In which way do you want to compare $X$ and $Y$? Whether they come from the same distribution or compare their mean? I would still say that $n=10$ is very small ...

Comment: i want to compare their means, unfortunately its an expensive experiment to test the effect of a drug on an animal model. X represent data obtained before treatment and Y is after treatment ( in the same animal. )

Comment: For the normality ... you can also look at skenwess and kurtosis. They should be $0$ resp. $3$ for the normal distribution. This is applied in the Jarque–Bera test which is implemented in R. But again: $n=10$ is very small and conclusions are dangerous in my mind. Can you increase $n$? Taking different integrals?

Comment: For an before and after on the same object, I think Wilcoxon signed rank test (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) can be applied. You find it in R too. Look at the article - maybe this is the set-up that you are in.

Comment: @mickey If you like my answer, then you could accept it ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a large variety of tests on normal distributions. I think the most common tests are Shapiro-Wilk or Jarque-Berra (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test). But i think in most cases it is sufficient to evaluate the normality using a Quantile-Quantile Plot (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q–Q_plot).

Using R you might look at:

```
data = c(10,1,2,3,4.5, 3.123, 12, 5.645, 6.123, 10)
qqnorm(data)
qqline(data)
```

If the data points vary around the line without systematic deviations from it (e.g.: s-curve) you might assume, that the data is normal distributed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so now i have to compare two populations with sample size 9 and 8, one of them follows a normal distribution while the other does not. How do i compare these, using a non-parametric Mann-Whitney would do ?

Comment: Yes you will need to use non-parametric tests in this case. Actually I am no specialist in this field, but take care with the Mann-Whitney. If you want to compare the medians of the two populations (what this test is usually used for) the assumption is made, that both populations have the same shape. As one of your distributions is normal and the other is not this might be a problem in your case. Sadly I am not a specialist in non-parametric test and some1 else might be able to  tell you if the test is robust vs this kind of violation of the assumption and which alternative test you might use.